# Is There a way to resume a download using Flurl framework?

Tags: flurl

I am using the Flurl framework to call web service methods.
One of this method returns a file content as a Stream using FileStreamActionResult as a return value of my web service.
On the client side I am using the DownloadFileAsync extension method implemented in Flurl.
All is working good..

Now in case of very big file, I want the process to be able to resume at a point where the download could have been stopped (because loose of network...or even because the user has closed the app).

Is this possible with Flurl ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

No, Flurl doesn't provide that functionality.